# Rotation in OpenGL ES

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I am trying to rotate a sphere continuously on a given axis using this code:

```
gl.glRotatef(axisX, 0, 1, 0);
gl.glRotatef(axisY, 0, 0, 1);

axisX = (axisX+1)%360;
axisY = (axisY+1)%360;
```

The variables `axisX` and `axisY` are both being incremented by one right now which would make the rotation go in a diagonal direction up to the right. The object gets to about 45 degrees of rotation and then start to turn and start rotation the other way. How can I get it to continuously rotate on an axis other than just x and y by themselves?

Note: I am trying to hook up a virtual joystick to control the `axisX` and `axisY` values and have the sphere rotate on the axis represented by the joystick. If anyone has any advice on that, that would be great as well.

**Edit:**
I've change it so that if I use `gl.glRotatef(angle, axisX, axisY, axisZ);` that it works and keeps the rotation going, but the rotation isn't smooth, it looks like the rotation starts over when I switch the rotation axis.

Comment: Have you tried using loadidentity? post here more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glLoadIdentity(); // Reset rotation and give a new one
glRotatef(theta[0],1.0,0.0,0.0);
glRotatef(theta[1],0.0,1.0,0.0);
```

The first argument is the angle, then the axis you want to pivot around.

About your edit: Looks like you are mixing axis and angles here. The axis should a unit length vector and the angle go from 0 to 2*PI.

Another way would be to use quaternions, then transform the quaternion to matrix and load the matrix as your current modelview matrix.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yeah fixed that, long time not used the fixed pipeline.

Comment: Thanks! Yea that does help a lot actually. I was able to set up a quaternion using the axis and angle, and then convert it to a matrix and use glMultMatrixf() to transform the modelview matrix. The rotations stay continuous now. Do you have any thoughts about how I could map a 2D joystick to the axis-angle rotation for the quaternion?

Comment: Whats wrong in your first approximation? (use the joystick displacements as the 'amount' of angle you want to apply).

Comment: Right now I'm trying to map the axis rotation values to a specific quadrant of the joystick coordinates. So if the joystick is pointing in the upper right(first quadrant) then I would determine the angle between the y-axis and vector formed from the origin to the joystick position. to determine how much to rotate. As soon as the axis values change however, the next rotation isn't around the correct axis.